# byte[] to int and viceversa java

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, arrays

I have a method that converts int to byte[]

```
private static byte[] intToBytes(int i)
{

 byte[] integerBs = new byte[MAX_INT_LEN];
 integerBs[0] = (byte) ((i >>> 24) & 0xFF);
 integerBs[1] = (byte) ((i >>> 16) & 0xFF);
 integerBs[2] = (byte) ((i >>> 8) & 0xFF);
 integerBs[3] = (byte) (i & 0xFF);
 return integerBs;
}
```

Let's say I try to convert the integer 4 to bits:

```
byte[] lenBs = intToBytes(4);
int a=(int)lenBs[0];
System.out.println("result:"+a);
```

The value of MAX_INT_LENGTH is 4

I get result:0 for every int that I put as a parameter for the method.Please tell me where i went wrong.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lenBs[0] is just getting:

```
integerBs[0] = (byte) ((i >>> 24) & 0xFF);
```

... which in the case of i = 4, integerBs[0] == 0.

Comment: then how should I convert the byte array to int ? a=(int)lenbs[3] ?

Comment: @EmilGrigore: You need to reverse the steps you did when converting the `int` to a `byte[]`.

Comment: I think i found this method that does the trick:java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();

Comment: No, an integer cast of a byte just casts that byte.  I would simply reverse the code in intToBytes().  There are other techniques (E.g. via ByteBuffer), but that would be using two very different styles in the same code.

Comment: @EmilGrigore - I think you will learn more if you stop looking for cut-and-paste solutions, and take the time to *read* and *understand* the code.